# Как из строки времени (hh::mm::ss.SSS) вытащить минуты?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, время

Есть строки (их очень много) вида: `String s1 = "10:11:23.555"`, т.е. формата hh::mm::ss.SSS.  Нужно **выделить минуты**.
Пробовал так:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\:)(\\d+)(\\:)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
System.out.println(m.group());
```

Не помогло, возможно чего-то не понимаю.

---

Возможен другой подход: преобразовать исходную строку к какому-то формату Time, но на ходу не могу вспомнить подходящий класс.

Comment: Минуты это MM, а mm это месяц.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, во всех примерах, что я видел использовалось "mm".

Comment: regex неверный: попробуйте `"^\\d{2,2}:(\\d{2,2})):.*"`. И еще, перед `group` нужно использовать `if (m.find())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зачем использовать регулярное выражение для такой примитивной задачи?

```
String s1 = "10:11:23.555";
String[] tokens = s1.split(":");
String minutes = tokens[1];
```

**UPDATE:** Раз автор вопроса озабочен производительностью, а @MedvedevDev интересуется устройством [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), вопрос переходит в статус более-менее интересных, и я не могу не развернуть ответ.

Прежде всего надо заметить, что реализация методов стандартной библиотеки может отличаться в разных реализациях JVM или даже разных версиях одной и той же JVM. Причём метод может [пробрасывать вызов в Сишный код](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function), использующий [SIMD-инструкции процессора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD), как это делает [String.indexOf()](https://gist.github.com/apangin/7a9b7062a4bd0cd41fcc#file-hotspot-jvm-intrinsics-L66) например.

В Java 8 на HotSpot метод `split`, как правильно заметил @Nick, использует регулярные выражения только для аргумента из нескольких символов или содержащего мета-символы. Иначе положения разделителя перебираются в цикле с помощью уже упомянутого мной `indexOf`:

```
int off = 0;
int next = 0;
while ((next = indexOf(ch, off)) != -1) {
    list.add(substring(off, next));
    off = next + 1;
}
```

Посмотреть можно [здесь](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2316).

Грешно было бы не проверить разницу в скорости между таким подходом и использованием регулярного выражения. Я набросал для этого тест [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/):

```
public class SplitBenchmark {
    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class BenchmarkState {
        public List<String> strings;
        public Pattern groupPattern;
        public Pattern splitPattern;

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void setup() {
            groupPattern = Pattern.compile(":(\\d+):");
            splitPattern = Pattern.compile(":");

            Random random = new Random();
            strings = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100_000)
                               .mapToObj(x -> random.ints(0, 99)
                                                    .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%02d", i))
                                                    .limit(3)
                                                    .collect(Collectors.joining(":")))
                               .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void regexGroupMatching(BenchmarkState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.strings.size(); i++) {
            String s = state.strings.get(i);

            Matcher m = state.groupPattern.matcher(s);
            if (m.find()) {
                String minutes = m.group(1);
                blackhole.consume(minutes);
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void regexPatternSplit(BenchmarkState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.strings.size(); i++) {
            String s = state.strings.get(i);

            String[] tokens = state.splitPattern.split(s);
            String minutes = tokens[1];

            blackhole.consume(minutes);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void stringSplit(BenchmarkState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.strings.size(); i++) {
            String s = state.strings.get(i);

            String[] tokens = s.split(":");
            String minutes = tokens[1];

            blackhole.consume(minutes);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
SplitBenchmark.regexGroupMatching  avgt   25  10,382 ? 0,120  ms/op
SplitBenchmark.regexPatternSplit   avgt   25  17,235 ? 0,240  ms/op
SplitBenchmark.stringSplit         avgt   25   7,906 ? 0,069  ms/op
```

Как можно видеть, `String.split()` самый быстрый, а `Pattern.split()` существенно медленнее даже извлечения групп, чем я сам удивлён.

Comment: Возможно мне стоит дополнить вопрос: дело в том, что строк подобных очень много и не хочется создавать массивы строк просто так.

Comment: @Keyzj используйте только один массив. Использование регулярных выражений - это намного более требовательный к ресурсам процесс.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, всегда интересно было: а методы типа `split` на чем работают (под капотом), если не на регулярках?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, но как подметил товарищ ниже: мы не уходим от regex.

Comment: @MedvedevDev внутри split проверка стоит. Если символ один и он не спецсимвол, то строка разбивается без использования регулярки

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ и сравнение разных методов!

Answer (score 2):

Чем не устроил метод `substring`?

```
String s1 = "10:11:23.555";
String minutes = s1.substring(3, 5);
System.out.println(minutes);
```

Comment: Вполне возможен вариант, что формат строк измениться, хардкодить нет желания...

Comment: Если формат строк изменится, то что ві собираетесь доставать регулярным выражением?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, регулярку можно, например, запихать в конфигурацию

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Позиции символов тоже